# Can I trigger another key when I press the down key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I want to trigger **the Tab key** when I press **the down key**.

So when I press the down arrow key
it should have the same effect if use I the Tab key.

Does anyone know for my issue a jquery or javascript code? :)

Comment: Where is your code, what you try  ?

Comment: What is your *end goal*? What is the *purpose* of this behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post my whole theme.html. Becaus I need it for my mainpage.

Comment: @Piskvor my end goal is navigate on my page only with the down key. 

it should have the same effect when I use the tab key

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't trigger a different key based on a keypress, for good reasons. Otherwise, you could trick browsers into auto-completing passwords or other sensitive information or even cause a password manager to do a global autofill.

That said, if all you want to do is, say, make the down key jump from one form field to the next, like the tab key does, that's easy. Just intercept the keypress in question and check whether it is the down key (charCode 40). If it is, execute whatever code you want to use to handle the event.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this could possibly fix your problem

arrow keys are only triggered by onkeydown, not onkeypress
keycode for Down is 40

```
function convertDownToTab() {
  if(event.keyCode==40) {
    event.keyCode = 9;
  }
}
document.onkeydown = convertDownToTab;
```

Or Using jQuery, you can do this When you press the down arrow key (keyCode 40), the next input receives the focus.

```
$('input, select').keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode==40) {
    $(this).next('input, select').focus();
}
});
```

Hope this helps